# Angular 5 Best way to hide credentials in Http Post Method

Tags: http, post, angular5, credentials

For an `Angular 5` application, I am hitting a login web `API` with the credentials. I am sending the user credentials in request (POST) body. The credentials which I sent is clearly visible in browser form data. How can we hide the credentials while sending to API?

Form Data in Browser(image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there's basically two ways to treat credentials in a secure way (and it's not angular dependant):

- The whole connection is end-to-end encrypted, i.e. using https as transfer protocol, making use of SSL to encrypt the data. I think you would still see the value in your console, but no-one else should be able to detect.
- You don't store / send the password itself, but an anonymized version of it. I.e., you would store the hash of a password in a database, and as of that, you would also hash the value entered in the password field and submit that one.

So, I would conclude it's less an issue in terms of your angular (frontend) design, but more of the overall (security) architecture of the application middleware.

Comment: my application is using HTTPS in all environments other than local. Will look into the SSL to encrypt the data.

Comment: The SSL was kind of an obvious statement (but that added it to indicate that the issue is probably not that severe). Anyway, what about my remark of hashing the password (or combination of user Id and pw)? I think it's a best practice and should address your issue.

Comment: Any further feedback whether this was helpful, you solved it differently etc., please?

Comment: going to hash the password and userid as you said above. Thanks for your valuable time.